# How to close popup

Tags: jquery, html, css

how t close that bio-info popup please help me
how to implemented in above the code.

in html file

```
 <ul class="ch-grid">
  <li>
<div class="bioinfo">
 <h2>tooltips</h2>
/div>
```

in css file

```
.bioinfo {
    display: none;
    max-height: auto;
    max-width: 220px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: rgba(108,108,108, 0.5) 5px 5px 5px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    right: -150px;
    z-index: 100;
/*    background: #eeeded; f6f6f6*/
    background: rgba(246,246,246, 0.8);
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 15px 3px 3px 3px;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

In Jquery

```
$('.ch-grid > li').hover(function() {
        //$('.ch-item').click(function() {

            //alert('ddl');
            //$(this).css({position: 'relative', left: -200});
            $(this).css({position: 'relative', marginRight: 120});
            $(this).children('.bioinfo').show();
}, function() {
    $($(this).data('.bioinfo')).hide();
});
```

how t close that bio-info popup please help me
how to implemented in above the code.

Comment: `$('.bioinfo').hide();` ? And `/div>` needs begining `<`

Comment: i didnt get you can you explanin

Comment: Or please include your all your html and I may be able to help further.

Comment: i have used 
 $(this).css({position: 'relative', marginRight: 120}); for move left side when hover so how to set in previous position after mouse leave pls suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
$('.instance > li').hover(function() {
    $(this).css({position: 'relative', marginRight: 120});
    $(this).children('.bioinfo').show();
}, function() {
    $(this).children('.bioinfo').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('.ch-grid > li').hover(function() {
    $(this).css({position: 'relative', marginRight: 120});
    $(this).children('.bioinfo').show();
}, function() {
    $(this).children('.bioinfo').hide();
});
```

HTML

```
 <ul class="ch-grid">
  <li>
<div class="bioinfo">
 <h2>tooltips</h2>
</div>
```

Make sure you add the `<` on `/div>`

Comment: excellent but my requirement if mouse over the image position move to left and show pop .. but above the code is show and close pop as per my requirement but the position not re-size so how to re-size the position when mouse leave.

Comment: i have used 
 $(this).css({position: 'relative', marginRight: 120}); for move left side when hover so how to set in previous position after mouse leave pls suggest

Comment: So you want your tooltip to display to the right of the bullet point? Please provide a graphic / picture of what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you are looking for.

I added colors to your markup to show the different element boundaries. You can see that this is returning the margin to its previous setting.

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7MFeu/1/)</kbd>

```
$('.ch-grid > li').hover(
    function () {
        //hover IN
        //alert( $(this).attr('id') );
        $(this).css({position: 'relative', marginRight: 120});
        $(this).children('.bioinfo').show();
    }, 
    function () {
        //hover OUT
        $(this).css({position: 'relative', marginRight: 0});
        $('.bioinfo').hide();
    }
```